# Sudo etc/hosts file not working

Tags: command-line, terminal, sudo, hosts-file

I want to edit my etc/hosts file. In terminal/command line on a mac i have typed in sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit

Sometimes it asks for my password, I enter my password and nothing happened. Other times it doesn't even ask for a password and nothing happens. Why isn't this command working?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16593/how-do-i-start-texteditor-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try typing this instead.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```